# Dropdown always lists all values in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

My dropdown always lists all values all are visible every time.

**view**

```
<label>Choose Employees</label>
<select name="select_employee[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected>Select</option>
        <? foreach ($employee->result() as $var) 
            {?> 
                <option value="<?echo $var->emp_id;?>"><?echo $var->emp_name;?></option>
            <?}?>
</select>
```

This is the permanent view. Is this a css issue..?
Removing the array symbol it exists proper view..but I want to keep it as an array.

initially vie this way

Comment: You want it to be `multiselect`?

Comment: remove  `multiple="multiple"` and try may it's halp you. :)

Comment: @Arthi I don't get what you're asking for, and I might not be the only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `multiple="multiple"` in your code, which makes all the options visible because your user needs to be able to select more than one option.

Here is the documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Answer (score 2):

`<select name="select_employee[]" multiple="multiple" size="1">` will display two options.

> Default value is 1 for single select. If the multiple attribute is present, the default value is 4